# Does Google ban internally implemented mobile push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I want to implement my own push notification system. My question is does google will ban or show warning for my application cause I don't use its Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wether or not you decide to use FCM, you will have to create notifications locally when a message is received from server. There are no restrictions on local notifications so the answer is No, there are no restrictions or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - No, it does not.

It would be kinda hilarious if they punished(banned) developers for [creating notifications](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#builder), something that's pretty vital in many applications.